# Opera Sync and chrome.storage.sync

Tags: opera-extension

I would like to know how is `chrome.storage.sync` synced in Opera.

The documentations talks about Opera Sync, is that Opera Link?
Is there any web page to guide the users on how to enable the `chrome.storage.sync` extension settings sync?

Does Opera button>More tools>Synchronise have anything to do with it?
The Chrome Sync implementation is much more straightforward to me.

Can't use it if I don't know if it will work on Opera's side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately chrome.storage.sync is not supported yet. There is no any connection to the Opera Sync.

Comment: Lastest Opera versions (tested on v.34) already support it, but don't forget to add "storage" in the manifest permissions param - https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage

Comment: @nevermind, are you sure about that?  as according to the Opera documentation at https://dev.opera.com/extensions/declare-permissions/ storage.sync is not supported.

Comment: @user280109 - the sync is not fully supported. I used chome.storage.sync in an extension and it works fine when you want just  to store some data, but it doesn't sync those data btw the different browsers/devices - http://forums.opera.com/discussion/1867018/chrome-storage-sync/p1

Answer (score 0):

According to the **Opera** documentation at
https://dev.opera.com/extensions/declare-permissions/
**chrome.storage.sync** is not supported.

If you try using **chrome.storage.sync** in your code the browser will "fallback" to using **chrome.storage.local** to maintain compatibility, so it won't actually sync settings across multiple browsers.